# What is strcpy in Java?

Tags: java

What is strcpy in Java?

```
String s1, s2;

s1 = new String("hello");
s2 = s1; // This only copies s1 to s2.
```

Comment: @sp00m: No, that's untrue. It copies a reference. There's nothing magical about String in that respect - it's just that it's immutable. You can write your own immutable classes too. (If your comment were an answer, I'd have downvoted it - it's incorrect and misleading.)

Comment: I mean s2 = s1 only copies reference. I edited.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This statement:

```
s2 = s1;
```

copies the value of `s1` into `s2`. That value is just a reference, so now `s1` and `s2` refer to the same object. So if this were a mutable type (e.g. `StringBuilder`, or `ArrayList`) then you'd be right to be concerned.

However, `String` is immutable. You can't modify the object to change its text data, so just copying the reference is sufficient. Changing the value of `s2` to refer to a different string (or making it a `null` reference) will *not* change the value of `s1`:

```
String s1 = "hello";
String s2 = s1;
s1 = "Something else";
System.out.println(s2); // Prints hello
```

If you *really* want to create a new `String` object, you can use the constructor you're already (needlessly) using for `s1`:

```
s2 = new String(s1);
```

However, that's *very rarely* a good idea.

Comment: I wonder: has anyone ever encountered a real life example where a copy of the original was really needed?

Comment: @amit: not for immutable String, but for there are obvious legitimate reason to copy a  mutable StringBuffer

Comment: @amit: Yes, I did. When reading a lot of *very short* lines from a dictionary file, the standard libraries *used* to allocate a string with a backing array of at least 80 chars. The difference in memory usage between doing `line = new String(line)` and not was enormous. I believe things are better now.

Comment: @LieRyan: I was talking about an immutable `String`... The reasons to copy a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` are obvious I believe. @JonSkeet: Interesting! thanks for sharing.

Comment: @amit -- There are cases where pointer compares are being done, and it is desired to have two separate pointers/addresses for the same literal string value for some reason.  But this is quite rare.

Comment: @HotLicks: I am familiar with this concept - but mostly as educational, never encountered it in a real world project, and was just curious. I believe we are getting a bit off-topic, sorry for that :|

Answer (score 6):

String is immutable so you would never need to copy it. (Except in rare circumstances)

e.g.

```
s1 = new String("hello");
```

is basically the same as

```
s1 = "hello";
```

and

```
s2 = s1;
```

is basically the same as

```
s2 = "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

No `s2` will refer to the newly created string object along with `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1, s2;

s1 = new String("hello");
s2 = s1; // This only copies s1 to s2. Am I right?

s1="adsfsdaf";

System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s1);
```

you are right s1 and s2 print the string not the same string...
but while doing this for objects changes made in one object affect another ...there is a need of clone for object ..there is no problem with string

Comment: It would be no different for any other object, immutable or not.  The second assignment to s1 is setting a new value for the reference (pointer), not modifying the object.  Modifying the object would be something like `s1.someField = xyz;`.

Comment: ya for string that is right...for condition like this Object 0=new Object(); object o2=o; there is a need of clone..that is what i have said

Comment: The "clone" is only needed if the object may be modified in the future, and you don't wish for that modification to be "seen" from the copy.  There's nothing "magical" about immutable objects -- they simply lack any method for modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

String Constructor does the job very easily because the string objects in java are immutable

```
String st="hello";
String st1=new String(st);
```

OUTPUT will be of st1 is hello

Comment: Has nothing to do with immutability.  It's simply a question of whether you get separate objects or duplicate references to the same object.  Immutability simply means that if you do just duplicate the reference you're guaranteed that no later operation can change the object's value.